# Remover XNamespace in XElement c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialização, xml-namespaces

Estou precisando remover o XNamespace que entra como default em um retorno de rss. Segue o código abaixo:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XNamespace ns = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss";

         var item = new XElement(ns + "content",
         new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", ns),
         new XAttribute("duration", "512"),
         new XAttribute("type", "video/mp4"),
         new XAttribute("url", "http://tv-download.dw.de/dwtv_video/flv/gle/gle20140609_ghana_sd_sor.mp4"),
         new XElement(ns + "thumbnail", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", ns),
         new XAttribute("url", "http://www.dw.de/image/0,,17611287_403,00.jpg"),
         new XAttribute("type", "image/jpeg"),
         new XAttribute("height", "480"),
         new XAttribute("width", "853")),
         new XElement(ns + "title",
         new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", ns), "Video caption"),
         new XElement(ns + "description",
         new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", ns), "description"),
         new XElement(ns + "copyright",
         new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", ns), "Francisco Cunha, 2014"));


        Console.WriteLine(item);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Você pode por favor colocar na sua pergunta qual o XML esperado e qual o XML que está sendo gerado?

Comment: Eu preciso remover o valor xmlns:media="" devolvendo somente os valores dos nos sem ele por exemplo o valor do no <media:copyright>Francisco Cunha, 2014</media:copyright> nao assim <media:copyright xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss">Francisco Cunha, 2014</media:copyright> estou montando um rss e tenho que remover esse xmlns de todos os nos que estou montando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque você está forçando o nome do `namespace` como `media`:

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", ns),
```

Troque para:

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns, ns),
```

Isto deverá gerar o seguinte elemento raiz:

```
<content xmlns="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss">
...
</content>
```

Os demais elementos também devem ter o `"media"` retirado, para que as tags sejam geradas sem o nome do `namespace`.